# C# new operate bug?

Tags: c#, constructor, c#-6.0

```
public class ListTest
{
    public List<int> MyList;
    public ListTest()
    {
        MyList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}

var listTest = new ListTest()
{
    MyList = {4,5,6}
};
```

Do you know the value of `listTest.MyList`?

It would be `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

[image: enter image description]

Someone can explain that??

Answer (score 14):

It's not a bug, but a consequence of how the `{ ... }` initializer syntax works in C#.

That syntax is available for any collection type that has an `Add()` method. And all it does is replace the sequence in the braces with a sequence of calls to the `Add()` method.

In your example, you first initialize, in the constructor, the value with the first three elements. Then, later when you assign the `{ 4, 5, 6 }` to the property, that calls `Add()` again with those values.

If you want to clear the previous contents, you need to assign with the `new` operator, like this:

```
var listTest = new ListTest()
{
    MyList = new List<int> {4,5,6}
};
```

By including the `new` operator, you get both a whole new object, as well as the `Add()` values.

Answer (score 4):

```
var listTest = new ListTest() // This line will first call constructor of ListTest class . 
//As constructor adds 1,2,3 in list MyList will have 3 recrods
{
    MyList = {4,5,6} // Once you add this statement this will add 3 more values in the list .
   // So instead of creating new list it will Add 3 elements in existing list
};

//Hence total 6 records will be there in the list
```

Answer (score 3):

This syntax simply calls `.Add` *after* constructor finished. As result you get 1,2,3 from constructor and than 4,5,6 added one by one.

Comment: But it's assign operate . It's equal with .add ??

Comment: @L.Tim, it _seems_ an assign operator, but it's not. It's just syntactic sugar for a loop over the items between `{}` adding those items one at the time to an _already initialized_ collection.